# How to customize the tab shortcode to apply only for one product

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have created a tab using "tab responsive" plugin. I want that tab to apply under the product image and only for one product. I use the following code and manage to apply under the product image. But the shortcode is applying to all the products. How can I customise this code just apply for one product.

Thank you.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'enfold_customization_extra_product_content', 15 );

function enfold_customization_extra_product_content() {

    echo do_shortcode("[your_shortcode]");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check against the product id like this:

```
function enfold_customization_extra_product_content() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->get_id() == '123' ) { // change 123 to your product ID
        echo do_shortcode("[your_shortcode]");
    }
}
```